# Postgres Autovacuum Progress Monitoring

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have an `autovacuum (to prevent wraparound)` happening on one of my tables for almost 4 days. I'm wondering if there is any way for me to tell if it's not keeping up with the amount of updates/deletes that are happening.

For reference, I am using Postgres 9.6 on Google CloudSQL. They have a known issue where `pg_stat_progress_vacuum` returns `null` for everything.

I've also been checking `pg_stat_all_tables` and have noticed that `n_dead_tup` for my table is going up instead of down, but I'm not sure if this number would be aware of the autovacuuming that is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad luck. If you have a hosted database, and the monitoring view is broken, there's nothing you can do.

To speed up autovacuum as much as possible, increase `maintenance_work_mem` and lower `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`. But that won't have an effect on an already running autovacuum worker.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you know if looking at n_dead_tup in pg_stat_all_tables is a reliable way of telling if the autovacuum won't complete? My value keeps going up, but I'm not sure if it's because it's not aware of the vacuuming taking place.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub, check if there any connection status show in `idle in transaction` if you find any then better to kill them . And also if your tables are larger then consider to decrease `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor`.  and the final solution `VACCUM FULL` or do `pg_pack`.

Comment: @Rj_N Killing sessions that could block autovacuum is alright. Decreasing the scale factor or running `VACUUM (FULL)` are bad advice and will harm rather than help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe @Rj_N: do either of you know if `n_dead_tup` in view `pg_stat_all_tables` is a sign that the vacuum is removing dead rows slower than new ones are being added?

Comment: No, `n_dead_tup` is only updated when `VACUUM` is done.